# Как из кеша формы html достать пароль?

Tags: firefox

Есть ссылка на страницу `https://twitter.com/search?f=tweets&q=live%23periscope&src=typd` и в cash формы *.html сохранен пароль.

**Вопрос:** как посмотреть сохраненный пароль?
[image: парольсохраненныйв cash , MozillaFirefox?]

Comment: Как из браузера достать сохранённый пароль? Возможно вам поможет саппорт https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/password-manager-remember-delete-change-and-import

Comment: браузер Firefox, удален давно, вопрос не актуален.